# Как связать кнопки алфавита со списком городов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть модальное окно с длинным списком городов

```
<div class="city_block">
  <a>Абакан</a>
  <a>Архангельск</a>
  <a>Архипо-осиповка</a>
  ...
</div>
```

И рядом кнопки алфавита

```
<div class="letter_block">
  <span>А</span>
  <span>Б</span>
  <span>В</span>
  ...
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с буквой алфавита список городов проматывался вверх или вниз до первого города, начинающегося на эту букву?

Comment: якорные ссылки.

Comment: Список находится в модальном окне. Нужно, чтобы оно не закрывалось, проматывалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="city_block">
  <a id='a'>Абакан</a>
  <a>Архангельск</a>
  <a>Архипо-осиповка</a>
  ...
</div>
<div class="letter_block">
  <a href='#a'>А</span>
 ...
</div>
```

Вроде бы так это делается

Comment: Список находится в модальном окне. Нужно, чтобы оно не закрывалось, а проматывалось.